# how to add item to table view with int value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I add numbers to my table cell and add the numbers to a total label? wWhen I add a item like ps2 How can I also add the price to the table cell and add it to my total label? This is a problem I have been trying to solve for 3 weeks.

My table so far:

[image: my table]

My ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! //1.

        let text = data[indexPath.row] //2.

        cell.textLabel?.text = text //3.

        return cell //4.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

    var data = ["pizza"]
    var total = 0


    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name", message: "Add a new name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Spice", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in
            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let nameToSave = textField.text else { return }

            self.total += 2000
            self.totalLabel.text = "Total Bill is: $\(self.total)"

            self.data.append(nameToSave)
            self.tableView.reloadData()                       
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)


        alert.addTextField()

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by having a data model that isn't just an array of `String`.

Comment: how do I do that? can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

- Create an appropriate data model for example

  ```
  struct Model {
      let name : String
      let price : Double
  }
  ```
- In the controller create `data`

  ```
  var data = [Model]()
  ```
- In viewDidLoad populate the data source array for example

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     data = [Model(name: "Pizza", price: 4.99), Model(name: "Burger", price: 2.99)]
     tableView.dataSource = self
  }
  ```
- Whenever you reload the table view sum up the prices

  ```
  totalLabel.text = String(data.map{$0.price}.reduce(0.0, +))
  ```

Comment: I am little confused with this method, how do I get it to populate on the tableview and how do I enter my number into the table?

Comment: I wrote *simple solution* because it shows you only how to use a custom struct as data model. The question does not contain information how to populate the table view and enter the number.

Comment: Thats what I am having trouble doing is entering the data and adding the int totals.

Comment: There are many options: An alert view controller with associated text field like in the question, a popup view controller attached to an UI element, a text field in the cell with callback or a separate view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your help. at least I got some direction. I am new to iOS development and I am always learning I will up date you when I complete it.

Comment: can I put the model in a separate file?

Comment: I figured out how to use a struct and I got it working and I have learned a lot. thanks for the help!

Comment: ["id": 2, "speciality": Andrologist, "price": 2000.00]

This is my array model

Comment: String(data.map{$0.price}.reduce(0.0, +)) in this ...map{$0.price}.reduce(0.0, +) shows error i m using swift 4 @vadian

Comment: struct SelectedSpecialization {
    
    var id:String?
    var price:String?
    var special:String?
    
    init(id:String,price:String,special:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.price = price
        self.special = special
    }
}

this is my struct model . and i have to add price and in json prices comes like...2000.00 as string

Comment: @DilipTiwari It's a type mismatch: `Double` is not `String`. Add a computed property `var priceAsDouble : Double = { return Double(price) ?? 0.0 }` and use `priceAsDouble` in the `reduce` line.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to start by storing your prices as Ints, one option is to store them in an array. Keep in mind if you are going to use decimals you will need to use a different type.

You can then add up an array of ints with something along these lines...

```
let prices = [...]
totalPrice = prices.reduce(0, +)
```

Some more info:

This uses Array's reduce method (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_6reduceu__Rq_S__Fq_FzTqd__7combineFzTqd__qqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Element_qd___qd__)), which allows you to "reduce a collection of elements down to a single value by recursively applying the provided closure". We give it 0 as the initial value, and then, essentially, the closure { $0 + $1 }. Of course, we can simplify that to a single plus sign, because that's how Swift rolls.

You can then assign the `totalPrice` value to the label of the `sum` table cell.