# Adding values in a tableView to a label Swift4

Tags: xcode, swift4

I am trying to take the values that I add to the `tableview` and add them to my `totalLabel`. I have attached my code and a screenshot below to help. In the example, it does not add to the `totalLabel`. item 1 plus item 2 should be  $2 and let's say I add another item for $5 then it would be $7.

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!


var items: [Item] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item", message: "Add item And Price", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (UITextField) in
        UITextField.placeholder = "Enter Item Name"
    }
    alert.addTextField { (UITextField) in
        UITextField.placeholder = "Enter Item Price"
        UITextField.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        let content = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let content2 = alert.textFields![1] as UITextField
        let value = "\(content2.text!)"

        let item = Item(itemName: "\(content.text!)", itemPrice: Double(value)!)


        self.items.append(item)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        guard let total = Double(self.totalLabel.text!) else { return }
        let sum = String(total + Double(value)!)
        self.totalLabel.text = sum


    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let items = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = items.itemName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(String(items.itemPrice))"

    var totalAmount = 0.0
    for value in self.items {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + items.itemPrice

        print(value)
        print(totalAmount)

    }

    totalLabel.text = "Total is $\(totalAmount)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Grocery List"
}

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And what is your issue?

Comment: it does not add to the label item 1 plus item 2 should be should be $2 and lets say I add another item for $5 then it would be $7

Comment: That should be on your question. Also what’s your tableview code ?

Comment: I updated the post and code to show my issue

Comment: show me how many item contain in array and what end result you want?

Comment: it is as many as the user wants to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801229/how-to-add-item-to-table-view-with-int-value) you have to sum up the `price` values in the `items` array

Create a function which reloads the table view **and** updates the `total` label

```
func reloadAll() {
   tableView.reloadData()
   let totalAmount = String(items.map{$0.itemPrice}.reduce(0.0, +))
   totalLabel.text = "Total is $\(totalAmount)"
}
```

Then call this method **everywhere** you call `tableView.reloadData()` for example replace these lines in the alert action

```
self.tableView.reloadData()

guard let total = Double(self.totalLabel.text!) else { return }
let sum = String(total + Double(value)!)
self.totalLabel.text = sum
```

just with

```
self.reloadAll()
```

---

And delete the following lines in `cellForRow`. It's pointless to update the label in this method because the same computation is performed `items.count` times (the loop runs `items.count²` times!)

```
var totalAmount = 0.0
for value in self.items {
    totalAmount = totalAmount + items.itemPrice

    print(value)
    print(totalAmount)

}

totalLabel.text = "Total is $\(totalAmount)"
```

Answer (score 2):

just replace this for loop instead of existing loop in cellForRowAt

```
    for value in self.items {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + value.itemPrice
    }
```

Comment: ⚠️ This solution is very, very inefficient. Imagine you have 100 items in `items` so `cellForRow` is called a hundred times and this loop is performed a hundred times **per call** (total 10000 times) to update the label with always the same value. Horrible scenario.

Comment: @vadian yes you are right. he just want to know where is the problem in his code.not efficient way of doing it.tnx for commenting

Answer (score 0):

Update this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let items = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = items.itemName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(String(items.itemPrice))"

    var totalAmount = 0.0
    for value in self.items {
      totalAmount = totalAmount + items.itemPrice
    }

    totalLabel.text = "Total is $\(totalAmount)"
    return cell
}
```

I hope this is what you looking.

Comment: it is calculating wrong. I also had it print to the console when I entered the items I added 2 item pizza and milk. here is what its doing. this is from the  console Item(itemName: "pizza", itemPrice: 1.99)
1.99
Item(itemName: "pizza", itemPrice: 1.99)
1.99
Item(itemName: "milk", itemPrice: 2.0)
3.98
Item(itemName: "pizza", itemPrice: 1.99)
2.0
Item(itemName: "milk", itemPrice: 2.0)
4.0

Comment: so in array, total 5 items. pizza,pizza,milk,pizza and milk. you want end result is 1.99 + 1.99+2.0+1.99+2.0 = 9.97? is that you want?

Comment: pizza and milk I only added them once so the total should be 3.99, so let say I need another item for lets say 2.00 it should be 5.99

Comment: can you give me proper example with calculation? update your question